# Windows digital ruler which measures in percentage?

Tags: ruler

I've been trying to find a windows ruler that allows to measure in percentage for a long while without success, so asking in case you know of such a software.

Basically, I just need a ruler that's vertically adjustable (ie, the length of the ruler should be variable and always 100% in its maximum length), and then if you click on any part of that ruler it should tell you the %.

Have you ever seen a programme that allows you this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is it that you are wanting a percentage of? The screen? The browser? Some other app?

Comment: The length of the ruler itself, ie, thinking of a ruler than can be made longer or shorter (and that would be always 100%), and then clicking on any part of the selected length would indicate which % that is.

I need to use it on top of a PDF document, and the figures have different sizes, hence that the length of the ruler needs to be adjustable.

Comment: On a side note, wondering why someone has voted the question as -1, if they think this is a stupid question because they know the answer, at least they could have helped! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a simple ruler tool that can be downloaded  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/icqxor48gf1x3gm/VerticalPercentRuler.exe?dl=1). The source code can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9eptakmk1c49pc/VerticalPercentRulerSource.zip?dl=1).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey man, this is sooooooooooo helpful!!!!
Thank you so much, much appreciated!

Could you please upload another version that allows to measure starting from the bottom? ie, with 0% at the bottom and 100% at the top?

Comment: @mickael No problem, and if you know vb.net, i can give you the source code

Comment: @mickael OK, here it is: [Download Source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9eptakmk1c49pc/VerticalPercentRulerSource.zip?dl=1)

Comment: +1 for source. Without that I'd never suggest that someone use something like this though.